# Entire function with fixed values at some points

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ be complex numbers such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|=\infty$. Also, let $b_1,b_2,\ldots$ be complex numbers.

I wonder if it's true that there always exist an entire function $f$ such that $f(a_n)=b_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. [A version](http://mathoverflow.net/q/20711/6085) of this was asked and answered on MO (the answers include your version of the question, and more).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Wow interesting, thanks. The answers there look quite advanced. Can we do it simpler in this particular case?

Comment: Harald's approach (essentially a formula) is probably as explicit as one can hope for.